404 when creating a new route in express MDN tutorial
I am trying the challenge yourself portion of part 2 of the MDN Express tutorial. After creating the Express project they ask the following:
Create a new route in /routes/users.js that will display the text "You're so cool" at URL /users/cool/. Test it by running the server and visiting
http://localhost:3000/users/cool/ 
in your browser
I have tried and keep getting a 404 error
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();

 /* GET users listing. */
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.send('respond with a resource');
 });

 // this was for the challenge youself portion, to create something that appears at   /users/cool...but it wont work

 router.get('/cool', function(req, res, next) {
   res.send('You are so cool!');
 });

 module.exports = router;


Does the  /users work?

yes when i got to localhost:3000/users

Express is listening on /cool , not /users/cool. That's the mean of the 404 error. Be sure to read Express routing docs, here and here

router.get('/users/cool', function(req, res, next) {
res.send('You are so cool!');
});
I have tried this and it doesnt work either

I just had to restart the server, I thought it was being done automatically with nodemon when i refreshed the page. Thanks for your patience everyone!!
